# Differentiability of the function $f ( x ): = \sum _ { n \geq 1 } \frac { \sin ( x / n ) } { n }$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives

Consider the function $f ( x ): = \sum _ { n \geq 1 } \frac { \sin ( x / n ) } { n }$, What about the differentiability of $f$ on $\mathbb R$? Is it increasing?

Comment: See the paper$\ \ \   $  https://www.cs.purdue.edu/homes/wxg/slidesHL.pdf $\ \ \ $    by Walter Gautschi on this function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the function $f_n(x):=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{\sin(\frac{x}{k})}{k}$. It is obvious (by asymptotic comparison with $\sum \frac{x}{n^2}$ that $\lim_{n\to \infty}f_n=f$ pointwise

We  have $f'_n(x)=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\cos(\frac{x}{k})}{k^2}$. By [Weierstrass M-test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_M-test)
the series converges uniformly (let us call the limit $g$).

A simple application of the uniform convergence allows us to write

$$f_n(x)=f_n(0)+\int_0^x f_n'(t)dt\\
f(x)=\lim_{n\to \infty} f_n(x)=\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_0^xf_n'(t)dt=\int_0^x \lim_{n\to \infty}f_n'(t)dt=\int_0^xg(t)dt$$

Thus, thanks to the fundamental theorem of calculus $f'(x)=g(x)$.

$f$ is thus differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$

Concerning the fact that $f$ is increasing, a quick look at $f'(\pi)$ is sufficient to note that $f'(\pi)=-1+\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(\pi/k)}{k^2}\le-1+\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^2}=-1+\pi^2/6-1<0$, and thus $f$ cannot be increasing